# mysql count occurrence of a string

Tags: mysql

I need to count how many times a couple categories appear in a column.  They're storred as strings like Sports, Medicine, the column name is ct.category_name.

This is the query i'm  adapting.  I'd like a column for every category type.

```
select co.order_id, co.catalog_item_id, ct.category_name               
from customer_order as co
join item_category as ic on (ic.item_id = co.customer_id )
join category_translations as ct on (ct.category_id = ic.category_id)
where co.paid = 1 and co.customer_id = 22500 and ct.locale = "en"
```

When I put this in the select statement it counts everything, I can see why, but I'm not sure which direction to go.

```
count(CASE 
    WHEN ct.category_name = "sports" THEN ct.category_name 
     ELSE 0 
    end) AS 'sports'
```

Again, i'd like the count for each string to be its own column.  Any help would be much appreciated.

When I try:

```
select co.order_id, co.catalog_item_id, ct.category_name
, SUM(ct.category_name = "sports") AS `sports`
, SUM(ct.category_name = "medici") AS `medicine`


from customer_order as co

join item_category as ic on (ic.item_id = co.customer_id )
join category_translations as ct on (ct.category_id = ic.category_id)


where co.paid = 1 and co.customer_id = 22500 and ct.locale = "en"
```

It counts sports twice. Wrong place for the when? Results:

```
`23115  271708  sports  483 483`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It counts everything because `COUNT` increments its value for every not null value, and `0` is not `NULL`.

Possible solutions:

- Replace `0` with `NULL` OR
- Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

  ```
  SUM(CASE 
  WHEN ct.category_name = "sports" THEN 1
   ELSE 0 
  end) AS 'sports'
  ```

or even

```
SUM(ct.category_name = "sports") AS `sports`
```

Comment: Coo, but when I adapt for a second string, it is only counting the first one, and repeating it.  Should this not be in the select?

Comment: @jahrichie: I'm not sure I understand you. Show your exact code, guessing is not the best way of solving programming issues

Comment: I updated the first post with my attempt and result. Thanks in advance

Comment: @jahrichie: the query is correct. What if you change the second `"medici"` to `'zerkms'`? Would you see `0`?